# AngularJS Filter issue: Compare only part of string (substring)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Issue happens when i filtered the data using the string "home" and "home 123", if i filter for "home" then content related to "home 123" also selected. that means Boolean return true even for "home 123" if I filter for "home" that is substring. http://jsbin.com/jolik/1/edit

But if i use filter with strings which are not related "home" and "product" i got the exact result intended. see this JS Bin demo http://jsbin.com/rusab/1/edit

Please help in this issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>

  </head>

<body ng-controller="MyApp">
  <select ng-model="keyToDisplay" ng-options="key as key.key for key in keys"></select>
  <span>{{keyToDisplay.key}}</span>


  <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:{'key':keyToDisplay.key}">
    <h3>{{item.key}}</h3>
    <p>{{item.value}}</p>
  </div>
  <hr />

</body>
</html>
```

working Code : app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MyApp', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {key:"home",value:"hk1"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk2"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk3"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk4"},
    {key:"product",value:"pk1"},
    {key:"product",value:"pk2"},
    {key:"product",value:"pk3"},
    {key:"product",value:"pk4"},
    {key:"service",value:"sk1"},
    {key:"service",value:"hk2"},
    {key:"service",value:"hk3"},
    {key:"service",value:"hk4"}
  ];

  $scope.datafiltered = _.groupBy($scope.data, 'key');

  $scope.keys = _.unique($scope.data, 'key');

  $scope.keyToDisplay = $scope.keys[0];
}]);
```

Issue Code : app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MyApp', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {key:"home",value:"hk1"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk2"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk3"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk4"},
    {key:"home 123",value:"pk1"},
    {key:"home 123",value:"pk2"},
    {key:"home 123",value:"pk3"},
    {key:"home 123",value:"pk4"},
    {key:"service",value:"sk1"},
    {key:"service",value:"hk2"},
    {key:"service",value:"hk3"},
    {key:"service",value:"hk4"}
  ];

  $scope.datafiltered = _.groupBy($scope.data, 'key');

  $scope.keys = _.unique($scope.data, 'key');

  $scope.keyToDisplay = $scope.keys[0];
}]);
```

Comment: +1 for `key as key.key for key in keys` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for exact equivalence use [extended filter](http://jsbin.com/dakadoga/1/edit).

Look at ***true*** after filter argument.

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:keyToDisplay.key:true">
    <h3>{{item.key}}</h3>
    <p>{{item.value}}</p>
  </div>
  <hr />
```

more details at [filter docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)